# Tab buttons don't fade since rebranding

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

It has been brought to my attention that the buttons to change tabs no longer fade. Currently, if you hover over something like `Tags` or `Users`, it blinks to the right color, but if you check the web archive, it used to fade back when it was "Gaming": http://web.archive.org/web/20100826164709/https://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think the fade is worse.

Comment: Not sure if a bug or a deliberate design change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/conversation/in-which-jin-explains-why-the-tab-color-does-no-longer-transition). Jin said on chat this is intentional as it makes site take overs easier.